# Página não pega arquivos JS posteriormente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Gente estou com um problema, procurei na internet e não encontrei, vi que tem uma dúvida parecida aqui no Stack, mas que não resolveu o meu problema.

É o seguinte, eu tenho vários arquivos em JS, como por exemplo um de "Mostrar Mais", aonde ele busca mais notícias, ele pega essas próximas notícias de outro arquivo que é o buscar.php, agora o que acontece é o seguinte, algumas notícias tem galerias que utilizam JS, na página principal pega corretamente, porém quando eu clico em Mostrar Mais ele mostra as notícias mas quando eu clico pra ver a galeria não funciona, pra funcionar eu tenho que incluir aquele mesmo JS nessa página buscar.php, mas acontece que a página fica meio pesada, pois ela vai ter 2 JS iguais que fazem a mesma função. Isso é normal? O JS não pega arquivos posteriores?

OBS: Não coloquei aqui o código, por que é muito grande.

Comment: Coloque alguma parte que você acha interessante mostrar e passe o resto no pastebin.

Comment: Você ja tentou isolar a função ou o método que inicializa as galerias para apenas executa-la novamente após o carregamento do buscar.php?

Comment: Como assim? Isolar? Eu quero que ela funcione normalmente, mas quando chamar o buscar, também funcionar. Só isso

Comment: Você comentou que precisa incluir o javascript novamente para criar as galerias. Você poderia criar uma função para criar essas galerias a qual você apenas re-executaria, sem precisar incluir o javascript novamente. Similar à forma com que o Facebook renderiza os componentes de like, share e comments

Comment: Como eu faria para criar essa função? As galerias foram só um exemplo...

Answer (score 0):

Gente, eu fiquei quebrando a cabeça com isso durante dias, e não achava, e a solução era bem simples, segue aí pra quem está com esse problema:

$('body').on('click', '.curtir', function() {

Apenas colocar o $('body'). pois aí ele coloca na página posterior a função